# How do I put the focus on a modal dialog box using powershell?

Tags: powershell, modal-dialog

I found a script [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7sra4w/how_to_go_about_pressing_a_button/) (see below) that allows me to select a main window from powershell and then add some keypresses.  However, when the script selects the main window and not the dialog box I want to do key presses on to make it go away.  Is there some way to select the dialog box instead, or use keypresses to select it?

```
Function SendKey{
    [CMDLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [String]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Position=1)]
        $WindowTitle,

        [String[]]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Position=2)]
        $Key
    )
    Begin{ 
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $Dlls = @' 
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 
'@

    $WindowControl = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Dlls -Name "Win32WindowControl" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
    }
    Process{
        $WindowHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $WindowTitle } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle

        If($WindowHandle){
            $WindowControl::SetForegroundWindow($WindowHandle)

            Sleep 1

            $FocusHandle = $WindowControl::GetForegroundWindow()
            If($FocusHandle -eq $WindowHandle){
                ForEach($Press in $Key){
                    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Press")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

- has an *incidental* problem: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` suppresses subsequent errors, so that [`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$Press")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait) quietly fails, given that the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly is never loaded in your code (`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`)
- has a *fundamental* problem: Using `SetForegroundWindow()` with a process' *main* window will indeed set the focus on that main window even while a modal dialog is open - as a result, keystrokes may go nowhere.

The simplest solution is to use the `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]` type's static [`.AppActivate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.appactivate) method instead:

- `.AppActivate()` properly activates whatever window belonging to the target application is frontmost - as would be activated if you alt-tabbed to the application. This may be the main window or an open modal dialog, for instance.

```
Function SendKey {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [String]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 1)]
    $WindowTitle,

    [String[]]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 2)]
    $Key
  )

  Begin {
    # Load the required assemblies.
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, Microsoft.VisualBasic
  }
  Process {

    # Find the process with the main window title of interest.
    $procId = (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $WindowTitle }).Id

    If ($procId) { # Target application's process found.

      # Activate it by its process ID.
      [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($procId)

      # Send the keystrokes.
      ForEach ($Press in $Key) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($Press)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

To test the code:

- From a PowerShell window, dot-source the function above (define it in your session).
- Open a Notepad instance (run `notepad`).
- Switch to the new instance and make the file-open dialog visible (<kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>).
- Switch back to your PowerShell window and run `SendKey Notepad '{ESC}o'`

Notepad should be activated, the file-open dialog should be dismissed, and `o` should be typed in the main window (the document).

If there's no dialog open, then the `{ESC}` should have no effect and `o` should appear in the main window too.

*Caveat*: The keystrokes will be sent to whatever control inside the target window / target window's open dialog happens to have the keyboard focus.

Therefore, if you know what specific window / dialog will be open at the time you send the keystrokes, you can first send additional keystrokes that activate the specific control of interest.

For instance, if you expect the file-open dialog to be open, you could send `%n` - the equivalent of <kbd>Alt+N</kbd> - first, to ensure that the `File name:` text box has the input focus.
E.g., to send filename `file.txt`: `SendKey Notepad '%nfile.txt'`